# How to change the way tables/columns are named by Hibernate/Spring Roo?

Tags: hibernate, spring-roo

My tables are getting generated along side classes by using Spring Roo. However there is a convention that it is using to generate the table names etc.

Is there a way to override this convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom table names use `--table` parameter [as in documentation](http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=command-index#command-index-entity). For column names use `--column` parameter from [this reference](http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=command-index#command-index-field-commands).